# Create a Dynamic Nav on the Fly

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

I'm looking for the best way to create a complex navigation element on the fly. I have all of the elements in a database (title, id, parentId) and I want to efficiently take them out of the DB and display them correctly. I also want to collapse all of the navigation elements that aren't active. So if I was browsing through "Sofas" I wouldn't see "Chandeliers" or any of the categories under lighting but I would see "Lighting".

This is what I want the final product to look like:

- Furniture

  - Living Room

    - Sofas
    - Chairs
    - Ottomans
  - Bedroom

    - Beds
    - Nightstands
- Lighting

  - Chandeliers
  - Floor Lamps
  - Sconces
- Rugs & Textiles

  - Contemporary
  - Vintage

My current method is

1. write one SQL query that pulls down all of the category names, ids, and parent ids
2. Iterate through the categories and put into a sorted multi-dimensional array with child categories stored under their parents.
3. Iterate through the new array and add another entry to mark the appropriate categories as open (all categories are closed by default)
4. iterate through the array and write HTML

I'm trying to to this with as few interations as possible and I'm sure the code I have right now is inefficient. Especially step 2 I iterate through the array several times. There has to be a general solution to this (common?) problem.

Comment: why don't you mark the appropriate category as open during 2nd iteration while creating a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or some other client-side logic at all? If not, then the stuff you can't see can't be opened, and there's no reason to get/process that info...

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding a new field to your database table: `level`.
Main-categories will have `level` 0.
Sub-categories will have `level` 1.
Sub-sub-categories will have `level` 2.
etc.

This trick will help you to know which sub-categories to disable without 2nd iteration of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the perfect place to generate your html code using recursion.
I used this function a while ago. It is working with a multi-dimensional array (tree)

```
function buildMenu($menu_array, $is_sub=FALSE) {
      $attr = (!$is_sub) ? 'id="menu"' : 'class="submenu"';
      $menu = "<ul $attr>\n"; 
      foreach($menu_array as $id => $elements) {
          foreach($elements as $key => $val) {
              if(is_array($val)) {
                  $sub = buildMenu($val, TRUE);
              }
              else {
                  $sub = NULL;
                  $$key = $val;
              }
          }
          if(!isset($url)) {
              $url = $id;
          }
          $menu .= "<li><a href=\"$url\">$display</a>$sub</li>\n";
          unset($url, $display, $sub);
      }
      return $menu . "</ul>\n";
  }
  echo buildMenu($menu_array);
```

This adds css properties too. If you wish to mark the currently active page you can use the [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to find your current url. If you need some more functionality you can easily add them to `buildMenu()`

Using level as mentioned in the answer above will help too. If you were using the nested set model in your database I could also help you with my query which is a single select returning the whole menu data.